# Typescript: Access optional class property from method

Tags: typescript, class, methods

In typescript, I'm creating a class with optional properties and methods.
In a method of that class, I would like to access the type properties (in a type-safe way, so if they exist).

I've tried like this:

```js
class MyClass {
  body?: string;
  children?: MyClass[];

  static subs(): MyClass[] | undefined {
    if (this.children) {
      return this.children;
    }
  }
}
```

And got the following error:

```
Property 'children' does not exist on type 'typeof MyClass'.ts(2339)
```

How can I achieve this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Static methods cannot access instance properties.

Following works:

```
class MyClass {
  body?: string;
  children?: MyClass[];

  subs(): MyClass[] | undefined {
    if (this.children) {
      return this.children;
    }
    return undefined
  }
}
```

but can be simplified to:

```
 // ...
 
  subs(): MyClass[] | undefined {
    return this.children;
  }
```

Reflection (i.e. accessing type information at runtime) is not easily possible. You can [list properties](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/getOwnPropertyNames) of a object, but you get only the javascript types.